# Problem with IntelliJ - Cannot run simple Spring Application

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

I don't know what is wrong but I created a new Spring Application and tried to run it but I always get this error:

```
Error:Internal error: (java.lang.IllegalAccessError) class com.intellij.util.io.FileChannelUtil (in unnamed module @0x5db45159) cannot access class sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.nio.ch to unnamed module @0x5db45159
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.intellij.util.io.FileChannelUtil (in unnamed module @0x5db45159) cannot access class sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.nio.ch to unnamed module @0x5db45159
    at com.intellij.util.io.FileChannelUtil.setupUnInterruptibleHandle(FileChannelUtil.java:26)
    at com.intellij.util.io.FileChannelUtil.<clinit>(FileChannelUtil.java:18)
    at com.intellij.util.io.ReadWriteDirectBufferWrapper$FileContext$1.execute(ReadWriteDirectBufferWrapper.java:50)
    at com.intellij.util.io.ReadWriteDirectBufferWrapper$FileContext$1.execute(ReadWriteDirectBufferWrapper.java:42)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtilRt.doIOOperation(FileUtilRt.java:945)
    at com.intellij.util.io.ReadWriteDirectBufferWrapper$FileContext.<init>(ReadWriteDirectBufferWrapper.java:42)
    at com.intellij.util.io.ReadWriteDirectBufferWrapper.create(ReadWriteDirectBufferWrapper.java:27)
    at com.intellij.util.io.DirectBufferWrapper.getBuffer(DirectBufferWrapper.java:24)
    at com.intellij.util.io.ReadWriteDirectBufferWrapper.getBuffer(ReadWriteDirectBufferWrapper.java:16)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage$StorageLock.createValue(PagedFileStorage.java:631)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage$StorageLock.get(PagedFileStorage.java:558)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage$StorageLock.access$500(PagedFileStorage.java:466)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage.getBufferWrapper(PagedFileStorage.java:407)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage.getBuffer(PagedFileStorage.java:371)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage.putInt(PagedFileStorage.java:144)
    at com.intellij.util.io.ResizeableMappedFile.putInt(ResizeableMappedFile.java:222)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorBase.markDirty(PersistentEnumeratorBase.java:597)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorBase.<init>(PersistentEnumeratorBase.java:185)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentBTreeEnumerator.<init>(PersistentBTreeEnumerator.java:73)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorDelegate.<init>(PersistentEnumeratorDelegate.java:47)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.<init>(PersistentHashMap.java:149)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.<init>(PersistentHashMap.java:138)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.<init>(PersistentHashMap.java:129)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.<init>(PersistentHashMap.java:121)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.<init>(PersistentHashMap.java:114)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.AbstractStateStorage.createMap(AbstractStateStorage.java:124)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.AbstractStateStorage.<init>(AbstractStateStorage.java:27)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.FileTimestampStorage.<init>(FileTimestampStorage.java:27)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.ProjectStamps.<init>(ProjectStamps.java:39)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.ProjectTimestamps.<init>(ProjectTimestamps.java:19)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.load(BuildRunner.java:92)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:274)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:130)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:232)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
```

[image]

What am I missing? I use Java SE 16 and SDK 8

Comment: how did you try to run it?

Comment: Could you try using an other version of java (for ex java 11 LTS)

Comment: @Haidepzai RestController is not really an annotation for the entry point of the application. Did you try to run this code by running the main method?  Did you follow any tutorial/book when writing this code?

Comment: Yeah I tried to run the main method. Yup, I followed the slides from my professor and did the same setup like on the slides but I think something is wrong with my IntelliJ...

Comment: Okay I uninstalled IntelliJ and reinstalled and it seems to work. I still don't know why though...

Comment: you uninstalled intellij, re-installed it, re-imported the project, set your config, all in about six minutes?

Comment: About 10min, re-install and just create a new project

Comment: Top and right corner of the screen go to FinanceMgmntApplication click the arrow to view options and click edit configurations. Then check JRE to be from JDK 16 .

Answer (score 0):

try updating your Intellij IDE to the latest version.
Worked for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30415732)